# How Block or disable someones Customs Cells From Tableview with data from plist?

Tags: objective-c, nsarray, plist, ios7, xcode5

well I have 2 plist files:

[image: plist1]

And:

[image: plist2]

My StoryBoard is:

[image: StoryBoard]

the problem is when in my "Inicio" viewcontroller load data from the plist, I want Disable the cells when have the ENABLE=NO property & Enable the cells with ENABLE = YES, when I push or click in the cell, then go to the next view controller "PERSONAS" in this view controller load the 2nd Plist and in the same case I want go to the "DETALLE"viewcontroller only with the enabled cells that have ENABLED YES from plist.

for each viewdidload Im use:

```
 NSString *myListPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"MainMenuList"      ofType:@"plist"];
mainMenu = [[NSArray alloc]initWithContentsOfFile:myListPath];
NSLog(@"%@",mainMenu);

 NSString *myListPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"PersonasList" ofType:@"plist"];
Personas = [[NSArray alloc]initWithContentsOfFile:myListPath];
NSLog(@"%@",Personas);
```

And for show the tableview in the custom cell Im use:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

static NSString *simpleTableIdentifier = @"CustomCell";

NSLog(@"CARGANDO CELDAS");
MainMenuCell *cell = (MainMenuCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];
if (cell == nil)
{
    NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"CustomCelliPhone" owner:self options:nil];
    cell = [nib objectAtIndex:0];
}
//CustomCell*cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];

cell.Enabled.text = [[mainMenu objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]objectForKey:@"ENABLE"];
cell.TitleLabel.text = [[mainMenu objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]objectForKey:@"NAME"];
cell.ImageImageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[[mainMenu objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]objectForKey:@"IMAGE"]];

    if ([cell.Enabled.text isEqualToString:@"NO"])
    {
        NSLog(@"%@",cell.Enabled.text);
        cell.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
        cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
        cell.selected = NO;
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
    }

return cell;
```

}

in the Persona view controller I use the same code but not working, all customs cells are enabled, how can I fix that?, or am I wrong in something? or I did Forget Something please help guys!!

in the Simulator run in that way for ENABLE:

[image: ios71]

But I dont wanna the cells with ENABLE NO run!!:

[image: ios72]

Please help guys, im using XCODE 5 DP6, for iOS7, how is the best way for solve this!!! 
THANKS!!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for many intents, finally fix this!! well in each viewcontroller the code whit solve this is like:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

static NSString *simpleTableIdentifier = @"MainMenuCell";

NSLog(@"CARGANDO CELDAS");
MainMenuCell *cell = (MainMenuCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];
if (cell == nil)
{
    NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"MainMenuCelliPhone" owner:self options:nil];
    cell = [nib objectAtIndex:0];
}
//MainMenuCell*cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];

cell.Enabled.text = [[mainMenu objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]objectForKey:@"Enabled"];
cell.TitleLabel.text = [[mainMenu objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]objectForKey:@"Title"];
cell.ImageImageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[[mainMenu objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]objectForKey:@"Image"]];
//cell.ImageImageView.image = [[mainMenu objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]objectForKey:@"Image"];

    if ([[[mainMenu objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]objectForKey:@"Enabled"] isEqualToString:@"NO"])
    {
        NSLog(@"%@",cell.Enabled.text);
        cell.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
        cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
        cell.selected = NO;
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;

        cell.ImageImageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"NO.png"];
    }
    else
    {
    cell.ImageImageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"YES.png"];
    }

return cell;

    //------------------------------------------//
    //               THANKS anyway              //
    //          GRETTINGS FROM BOLIVIA          //
    //                ROCK ON!!!! n_n'          //
    //------------------------------------------//
 }
```